How do I check if the current page id matches in the template_redirect hook of a Wordpress plugin?
I'm working on a WordPress plugin and inside the template_redirect callback, I'm trying to check the current is part of a list of pages and then do a redirect. However, all the options I've tried haven't worked. I tried is_page($pageId) but it returns a boolean even when the id matches. get_the_ID() also returns false. get_queried_object_id() returns 0. I've also tried global $post but $post is NULL.
How do I check if the current page id matches a provided id, or list of ids from inside the template_redirect hook callback?
